# RangeError: Failed to execute 'compressedTexSubImage2D' on 'WebGl2RenderingContext': The ArrayBuffer/ArrayBufferView size exceeds the supported range

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, arraybuffer, unity-webgl

I am currently working on a multiplayer casino game. In the game, there is a poker game and after playing 4 rounds of it I was getting this error but when I reduced or compressed the textures now I am witnessing the error after playing 6-7 rounds of poker. So this means it somehow optimized or delayed the error but I am having difficulty finding the permanent fix. I would be grateful if anyone of you can help!
[image]

I tried manually reducing the max size of the textures and changed the compression type of texture. It improved the condition but didnt solved it.

Comment: You might want to paste the error as `text` and convert that by pressings `Ctrl+k` in your question. And you can copy the error message by `right clicking` on the error in your editor and then `copy error message`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.